# How to index the whole word only?

Tags: arrays, powershell

Suppose I have the following:

```
$CUBE_input = "ABC; DEF"
```

If I perform the following operation,

```
$($($CUBE_input.ToUpper() -split ';' -replace '(^\s+|\s+$)','' -replace '\s+',' ')[0])
```

I get `ABC`, and with `[1]`, I get back `DEF` (with no leading space thanks to the regex), as expected

However, if I don't have a semicolon split string, e.g.

```
$CUBE_input = "ABC"
```

and perform this operation again: `$($($CUBE_input.ToUpper() -split ';' -replace '(^\s+|\s+$)','' -replace '\s+',' ')[0])`

I get back `A`

I need to make it so that whether there is a semicolon delimited string or not, it only output the word every time, no characters.

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use `(...)` instead of `$(...)`**, which will result in an *array* of strings even in the single-element case:

```
($CUBE_input.ToUpper() -split ';' -replace '(^\s+|\s+$)','' -replace '\s+',' ')[0]
```

**`$(...)`, the [subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#subexpression-operator--) is rarely needed outside *expandable strings*** (if you need to embed expression and commands in `"..."` strings).

Outside of [expandable strings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445998/45375), you only need `$(...)` to embed *whole statement(s)* (such as `if`, `do`, `switch`, `foreach`, ...) in a larger expression or command, including providing a *statement* as the first segment of a pipeline.

**In order to embed as single *expression* or a single *command or pipeline* in a larger expression or command, use `(...)`, the [grouping operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#grouping-operator--), which avoids the *side effects of `$(...)`*** - see below.

---

As for **what you tried**:

**`$(...)` applies *pipeline* output logic** to the enclosed statements, which means:

- **Arrays resulting from expressions are *enumerated*** and the output objects are then *collected*, *situationally* in:

  - a regular `[object[]]` array, for *2 or more* output objects
  - an array element *as it itself*, in case of a *single-element* array (if you use `@()`, the [array-subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#array-subexpression-operator--) instead, you *always* get an `[object[]]` array)

Thus, by using `$(...)`, the single-element array produced by `-split` (and preserved by the `-replace` operations) was effectively *unwrapped*, and the element itself - the string `'ABC'` - was returned, and applying indices to *strings* extracts their individual characters; e.g. `'ABC'[0]`  returns `'A'`.

Note that the above also implies that a 2+-element array that is *strongly typed* is transformed to a new `[object[]]` array by `$(...)`; e.g.:

```sh
PS> $([string[]] ('a', 'b')).GetType().Name
Object[] # !! $(...) enumerated the array and 
         # !! collected the elements in a new [object[]] array
```

By contrast, `(...)` returns the expression's value as-is:

```sh
PS> ([string[]] ('a', 'b')).GetType().Name
String[] # OK: (...) preserved the array as-is
```