# add-member weirdness with type assignment

Tags: powershell, syntax, parameter-passing

In the code below, why does the [int] type assignment for name1 get ignored and is actually treated as part of the value? Bug?

```
$name1 = 4
$name2 = 4
$name3 = 4

$myObject = New-Object System.Object
$myObject | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name name1 -Value [int]$name1
$myObject | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name name2 -Value $($name2 -as [int])
$myObject | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name name3 -Value $([int]$name3)

$myObject
```

Output:

```
name1  name2 name3
-----  ----- -----
[int]4     4     4
```

Powershell version:

```
get-host | select-object version

Version       
-------       
5.1.19041.1023
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's good information in the existing answers, but let me attempt a systematic overview:

**tl;dr**

In order **to pass the output from an *expression*** (e.g. `[int] $name1` or 
`$env:HOME + '\foo'`), **or (nested) *command*** (e.g. `Get-Date -Format yyyy`) **as an *argument* to a *command*** (e.g. `Add-Member`), **enclose it in `(...)`**, the [grouping operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#grouping-operator--):

```bash
# Note the required (...) around expression [int] $name1
Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name name1 -Value ([int] $name1)
```

By contrast, **`$(...)`, the [subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#subexpression-operator--) is typically *not* needed in this scenario**, and its use can have side effects - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67695014/45375).

- In short: (Outside of [expandable strings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445998/45375), `"..."`), you only ever need `$(...)` to either enclose a *language statement* (such as an `if` statement or `foreach` loop) or *multiple* statements (any mix of commands, expressions, and language statements separated with `;`).

---

##### PowerShell's parsing modes:

PowerShell has ***two* fundamental parsing modes**:

- ***argument* mode**, which works **like *shells***.

  - In argument mode, the **first token is interpreted as a *command name*** (the name of cmdlet, function, alias, or the name of path of an external executable or `.ps1` script), **followed by a *whitespace-separated list* of *arguments***, where strings may be *unquoted*<sup>[1]</sup> and arguments composed of a mix of literal parts and variable references are *typically* treated like expandable strings (as if they were enclosed in `"..."`).
- ***expression* mode**, which works **like *programming languages***, where strings must be quoted, and *operators* and *language statements* such as assignments, `foreach` and `while` loops, *casts* can be used.

The conceptual [`about_Parsing`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing) provides an introduction to these modes; in short, **it is the *first token* in a given context that determines which mode is applied.**

A given statement may be composed of parts that are parsed in either mode, which is indeed what happens above:

- Because your statement starts with a *command name* (`Add-Member`), it is parsed in *argument* mode.
- `(...)` forces a new parsing context, which in the case at hand (`[int] $name1`) is parsed in *expression* mode, due to starting with `[`).

**What is considered a *metacharacter* (a character with special, syntactic meaning) *differs* between the parsing modes:**

- `[` and `=` are special only in *expression* mode, not in *argument* mode, where they are used *verbatim*.
- Conversely, a token-initial `@` followed by a variable *name* is only special in *argument* mode, where it is used for parameter [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Splatting).

Compound argument `[int]$name1` is therefore treated as if it were an *expandable string*, and results in verbatim string `[int]4`.

**Some expressions do not *require* enclosing in `(...)`** when used as command arguments (assume `$var = 'Foo'`):

- A *stand-alone* variable reference (e.g. `Write-Output $var` or `Write-Output $env:OS`)
- *Property access* on such a reference (e.g. `Write-Output $var.Length`)
- *Method calls* on such a reference (e.g. `Write-Output $var.ToUpper()`)

Note that these arguments are passed with their original data type, not stringified (although stringification may be performed by the receiving command).

**Pitfalls**:

- You sometimes need to use `"..."` explicitly in order to suppress property-access interpretation and have a `.` following a variable reference be interpreted verbatim (e.g. `Write-Output "$var.txt"` in order to get verbatim `foo.txt`).
- If you use `$(...)` as part of a compound argument *without* explicit `"..."` quoting, that argument is broken into *multiple* arguments if the `$(...)` subexpression *starts* the argument (e.g., `Write-Output $('a' + 'b')/c` passes *two* arguments, verbatim `ab` and `/c`, whereas `Write-Output c/$('a' + 'b')` passed just one, verbatim `c/ab`).
- Similarly, mixing quoted and unquoted strings to form a single argument only works if the argument starts with an *unquoted* token (e.g., `Write-Output One"$var"'$Two'` works as expected and yields verbatim `OneFoo$Two`, but `Write-Output 'One'"$var"'$Two'` is passed as *three* arguments, verbatim `One`, `Foo`, and `$Two`).

In short:

- The **exact rules** for how arguments are parsed are complex:

  - [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41254359/45375) summarizes the rules for *unquoted* arguments.
  - [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66161666/45375) summarizes mixing quoted and unquoted strings in a single argument
  - [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55614306/45375)) (bottom section) summarizes PowerShell's string literals in general.
- To be safe, **avoid use of `$(...)` outside `"..."` and avoid mixing quoting styles in a single string argument**; either use a (single) `"..."` string (e.g. `Write-Output "$(Split-Path $PROFILE)/foo.txt"` or ) or string concatenation in an expression (`Write-Output ('One' + $var + '$Two')`

---

<sup>[1] Assuming they contain neither spaces nor any of PowerShell's metacharacters (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66302956/45375)). While quoting typically takes the form of enclosing the entire argument in single or double-quotes, as appropriate (e.g. `'foo bar'`, `"foo $var"`), it is also possible to quote (escape) *individual* characters (e.g. `` foo` bar ``), using the backtick (`` ` ``), PowerShell's escape character.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

From the [`about_Parsing` help file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing):

> ### Argument mode
>
> When parsing, PowerShell first looks to interpret input as an expression. But when a command invocation is encountered,
> parsing continues in argument mode.
>
> Argument mode is designed for parsing arguments and parameters for
> commands in a shell environment. **All input is treated as an expandable
> string** unless it uses one of the following syntaxes:
>
> ...

You can enclose the code in a subexpression (`$(...)`) to avoid PowerShell treating `[int]$name1` as an expandable string, as you've already found :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is by design. You need to wrap in parentheses in order to evaluate the expression before passing it into the function.

Its the same if you try to put a function call there for instance:

```
$myObject | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name name1 -Value Write-Host
```

returns as:

```
name1
-----
Write-Host
```

And `Write-Host [string]2` returns `[string]2` not `2`