# dlurl : The term 'dlurl' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

Tags: powershell, variables, syntax

I am new to powershell and run into a weird error from:

```
\Downloads> dlurl = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-cli/AWSCLI64PY3.msi"
dlurl : The term 'dlurl' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ dlurl = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-cli/AWSCLI64PY3.msi"
+ ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (dlurl:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
```

Some suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike POSIX-compatible shells such as Bash, **PowerShell requires use of the `$` prefix symbol also when *creating* (assigning to) variables**, no just when *getting* their values.

Therefore:

```
$dlurl = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-cli/AWSCLI64PY3.msi"
```

<sup>Note: Consider using a `'...'` string for *verbatim* content.</sup>

Without the `$`, `dlurl` is interpreted as a *command name* and everything that comes after as its *arguments*, which explains the error you saw (no command by that name exists on your system).

See also:

- The conceptual [about_Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Variables) help topic.
- [about_Parsing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Parsing), which explains PowerShell's two fundamental parsing modes, *argument mode* (shell-like), and *expression mode* (programming-language-like); it is the first token of a statement that determines what mode is entered. A more systematic overview can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68487613/45375).