# Copy files from my current directory to new directory

Tags: powershell, sccm

so I am trying to copy 2 files from same folder that my Powershell script is in. I have created script  there and also 2 files Moveit1.txt, Moveit2.txt my script is this :

```
$ScriptDirectory = get-childitem -path $PSScriptRoot
Copy-Item $ScriptDirectory\MoveIt1.txt $env:USERPROFILE + "\AppData\Roaming\" -Force
Copy-Item $ScriptDirectory\MoveIt2.txt "C:\Program Files (x86)\" -Force
```

But unfortunately it says the files can't be found? But if I check just line $ScriptDirectory it shows where its located and with the files inside. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: does it work if you hardcode the source path?

Comment: Oh actually no, its says permission denied to file.

Comment: I tried running as administrator with hardcore source path that works, but when I try with my $PsScriptRoot it still messes up totally.. I really don´t know what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is one thing to note:

```
$ScriptDirectory = Get-ChildItem -Path $PSScriptRoot
```

`$scriptDirectory` will most likely contain the 2 *MoveIt* files in addition to your `.ps1` script. When you do:

```
$ScriptDirectory\MoveIt1.txt
```

I'm guessing it will end up being something like this when interpreted by `Copy-Item`:

```
path\to\script\script.ps1\path\to\script\moveit1.txt\path\to\script\moiveit2.txt\moveit1.txt
```

Try doing this instead:

```
Copy-Item (Join-Path $PSScriptRoot MoveIt1.txt) (Join-Path $env:USERPROFILE "\AppData\Roaming\") -Force
Copy-Item (Join-Path $PSScriptRoot MoveIt2.txt) "C:\Program Files (x86)\" -Force
```

---

Regarding your *Access Denied* issue and it working when ran as Administrator with hard-coded paths. You can put this at the top of the script so it elevates itself however this will pop an UAC prompt:

```
$invocation = "-File `"$PSCommandPath`""
Start-Process powershell -Verb Runas -ArgumentList $invocation
```

Answer (score 1):

The ***primary* problem** with your code **is a *syntax problem*** ([Santiago's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70411535/45375) addresses additional problems):

In order to **pass an *expression*** such as

```sh
$env:USERPROFILE + "\AppData\Roaming\"
```

**as a *command argument***, you need to **enclose it in `(...)`**.

Neglecting to do so passes *three* arguments, as the following simplified example demonstrates:

```sh
# !! WRONG: Passes *three* arguments instead of the result 
#           of the intended expression.
PS> Write-Output $env:USERPROFILE + "\AppData\Roaming"
C:\Users\jdoe
+
\App\Data\Roaming

# OK: (...) forces a new parsing context, in which the expression is recognized
#     as such.
PS> Write-Output $env:USERPROFILE + "\AppData\Roaming"
C:\Users\jdoe\App\Data\Roaming
```

As an aside:

- You could use `$env:APPDATA` to directly get the path of interest, and
- Even in cases where you do need to build a path from multiple strings, it may be simpler to use an *expandable string* instead of the `+` operator: `"$env:USERPROFILE\AppData\Roaming"` - in this particular case, because the string contains neither spaces nor other special characters (other than the intended `$`), the double quotes are even *optional*.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68487613/45375) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for all answers, I used some of my day to redo and now got a working script. Actually ended up with your idea $env:Appdata

Answer (score 1):

```
try {
    $scriptPath = $PSScriptRoot
    if (!$scriptPath)
    {
        if ($psISE)
        {
            $scriptPath = Split-Path -Parent -Path $psISE.CurrentFile.FullPath
        } else {
            Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "Cannot resolve script file's path"
            exit 1
        }
    }
} catch {
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "Caught Exception: $($Error[0].Exception.Message)"
    exit 2
}

Write-Host "Path: $scriptPath"


Copy-Item $ScriptPath\onexcuiconcif.xml -Destination "$env:APPDATA\Avaya\Avaya one-x Communicator" -Force
Copy-Item $scriptPath\InstallConfig.xml -Destination "C:\Program Files (x86)\Avaya\Avaya one-X Communicator" -Force
```