# (Powershell) Does powershell have some weird parentheses/bracket balance rules?

Tags: powershell, error-handling, brackets, unexpected-token

My powershell acts very strangely when I try to make a function. To demonstrate, Here is a basic function that, I dunno, calculates the quadratic formula:

```
  1 function Get-Quadratic {
  2
  3 [CmdletBinding()]
  4
  5 param (
  6         [Parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory = $true)]
  7         [int32]$a
  8         [Parameter(Position = 1, Mandatory = $true)]
  9         [int32]$b
 10         [Parameter(Position = 2, Mandatory = $true)]
 11         [int32]$c
 12 )
 13
 14 Write-Output $a + " " + $b + " " + $c
 15 }
```

And if you were to try loading this in with `. .\quadratic.ps1`, you get:

```
At C:\Users\(me)\Desktop\Cur\playground\quadratic.ps1:7 char:11
+     [int32]$a
+              ~
Missing ')' in function parameter list.
At C:\Users\(me)\Desktop\Cur\playground\quadratic.ps1:1 char:24
+ function Get-Quadratic {
+                        ~
Missing closing '}' in statement block or type definition.
At C:\Users\(me)\Desktop\Cur\playground\quadratic.ps1:12 char:1
+ )
+ ~
Unexpected token ')' in expression or statement.
At C:\Users\(me)\Desktop\Cur\playground\quadratic.ps1:15 char:1
+ }
+ ~
Unexpected token '}' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingEndParenthesisInFunctionParameterList
```

I have followed tutorials down to the pixel when trying to make functions, but my powershell doesn't seem to like even the most basic commands. If it helps, my version is

```
Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      1      19041  1320
```

Comment: You are missing the commas to separate each parameter

Comment: Thanks, @Abraham - that is indeed the _primary_ problem: parameter declarations must be `,`-separated. The linked duplicate explains the _secondary_ problem with `Write-Output $a + " " + $b + " " + $c`.

Comment: @Abraham, given the two distinct problems in the question, I've decided to reopen it.

Answer (score 2):

[Abraham Zinala](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14903754/abraham-zinala) provided the crucial pointer with respect to your code's ***primary* problem**:

- The individual parameter declarations inside a `param(...)` block must be `,`-separated.
- While the conceptual [about_Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions#functions-with-parameters) does state this requirement, it may not be *obvious*, given that in other contexts (`@(...)`, `$(...)` and `@{ ... }`) separating elements by *newlines* alone is sufficient. In fact, there is an existing feature request to make the use of `,` *optional* - see [GitHub issue #8957](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/8957).

The ***secondary* problem** is that `Write-Output $a + " " + $b + " " + $c` won't work as you expect:

- *Expressions* - such as string concatenation with the `+` operator in your case - require *enclosure in `(...)`* in order for their result to be passed as a *single* command argument - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68487613/45375).