# PowerShell Class Constructor - Can't Assign Variable Value

Tags: powershell, class, constructor

I’m writing a PowerShell class as follows:

```
class FileTransferStatus {

    $totalBytesToTransfer
    $bytesLeftToTransfer

    FileTransferStatus([System.IO.FileInfo[]]$files)
    {
        this.$totalBytesToTransfer = 0
        foreach ($file in $files) {
            this.$totalBytesToTransfer += $file.length
        }
        this.$bytesLeftToTransfer = this.$totalBytesToTransfer
    }
}
```

I’m getting an error on the last line of the constructor, which tries to initialize **$bytesLeftToTransfer**. The message is: **Variable is not assigned in the method.**

Anyone know what this message means, or how to fix the problem?

Comment: you have 4 typos: `this.$totalBytesToTransfer` should be `$this.totalBytesToTransfer`

Comment: Wow. I can't tell you how long I stared at that screen without noticing the misplaced dollar sign.  Of course the cryptic error message didn't help much. But all's well that ends well.  Thanks for the quick turnaround!

Comment: A note to potential close-voters: While to those intimately familiar with PowerShell this can be seen as a mere _typo_, to the less initiated there are syntax issues well worth exploring, so I suggest keeping this question open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Santiago Squarzon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15339544/santiago-squarzon) has provided the crucial pointer in a comment:

- All instances of `this.$totalBytesToTransfer` should be `$this.totalBytesToTransfer` instead.

While to users already familiar with PowerShell [`class`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Classes) your code could be seen as a mere *typo*, the required **syntax is worth explaining**:

- The [automatic `$this` *variable*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#this) refers to the instance at hand.
- To **refer to a *property*** of the instance at hand, you ***must use `$this`* combined with the usual [dot notation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#member-access-operator-), but *without `$`- prefixing the property name*** - even though properties must be *declared* with that prefix; that is:

  - To *declare* a property named `TotalBytesToTransfer`, you must use *variable* syntax, which requires `$`: `$TotalBytesToTransfer`
    (typically declared with a *type*, e.g. `[long] $TotalBytesToTransfer`).
  - To *access* that property, you must use `$this.TotalBytesToTransfer`

The **surprising aspects** are:

- Compared to C#:

  - PowerShell *requires* the equivalent of `this` - `$this` - to refer to instance properties, which is *optional* in C# (both for properties and fields; the latter have no PowerShell counterpart).
- Compared to other parts of PowerShell:

  - Property-defining `class` instance variables aren't *implicitly* in scope as such in instance methods, whereas the loosely analogous *parameter*-defining variables in *function and scripts* are.

---

As for **what you tried**:

> Anyone know what this message means?

Error message `Variable is not assigned in the method.` is trying to tell you that, inside a given method, you attempted to reference a *variable* that wasn't also *defined earlier in the same method*, which was triggered by the accidental reference to non-existent variable `$totalBytesToTransfer`.

- As noted above, *property*-defining variables *aren't* implicitly accessible, and any variable references must be to *method-local* variables, i.e. to variables *defined earlier in the same method*.

  - The exception are variable references with an explicit *scope specifier*, such as `$global:foo`; however, such references are best avoided in classes, so as not to break encapsulation.
- The error message - cited as of PowerShell 7.3.4 - *could be improved*, which is the subject of [GitHub issue #19767](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/19767).

The reason only the *last* of your four `this.$totalBytesToTransfer` references triggered the error is rooted in the fundamentals of PowerShell's syntax, which combines shell-like syntax with syntax familiar from traditional programming languages via distinct *parsing modes* (see the general information in the bottom section):

- Perhaps surprisingly, `this.$totalBytesToTransfer` is valid as a *verbatim command name* in PowerShell, i.e. as an identifier *at the start of* a  statement, so there's no *syntax* problem.

  - E.g., you can define a function literally named `this.$totalBytesToTransfer` and call it:

    ```bash
    function this.$totalBytesToTransfer { 'hi!' }
    this.$totalBytesToTransfer  # -> 'hi!'
    ```
- However, when the same token is used as a command *argument*, `$totalBytesToTransfer` *would* get expanded (interpolated), i.e. treated *as a variable reference*; that is, `this.$totalBytesToTransfer` is *implicitly* treated like an [expandable (double-quoted) string (`"..."`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings):

  ```bash
  $totalBytesToTransfer = 42
  Write-Output this.$totalBytesToTransfer # -> 'this.42'
  ```
- Given the above, your `this.$totalBytesToTransfer` tokens are interpreted as follows:

  ```bash
  # Call to (hypothetical) command 'this.$totalBytesToTransfer' 
  # with arguments '=' and 0
  this.$totalBytesToTransfer = 0

  # Call to (hypothetical) command 'this.$totalBytesToTransfer' 
  # with arguments '+=' and the value of the .length property of the
  # object stored in variable $file.
  this.$totalBytesToTransfer += $file.length

  # Call to (hypothetical) command 'this.$totalBytesToTransfer' 
  # with arguments '=' and the concatenation of 'this.' and the
  # the value of a (hypothetical) $totalBytesToTransfer variable.
  this.$bytesLeftToTransfer = this.$totalBytesToTransfer
  ```
- In the *last* statement above, the hypothetical `$totalBytesToTransfer` variable *isn't previously defined inside the method at hand*, which causes PowerShell to report the error you saw.

---

Generally, note that PowerShell - as both a *shell* and a (very capable) *scripting language* - of necessity needs to marry two distinct syntax worlds:

- *shell commands* (commands followed by whitespace-separated arguments) vs.
- *expressions* (operator-based operations and method calls), as in traditional programming languages).

This necessitates **two distinct *parsing modes***, as described in [about_Parsing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Parsing).

In short: The *start* of each statement determines which of the two parsing mode applies, which also applies to *nested* statements. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68487613/45375) for background information.

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to give such a comprehensive answer. I especially liked your comparisons to other languages.  I think my years of exposure to Java & C++ may have contributed to my using the wrong syntax. But all seems well now. Once again Thank you!

Comment: Egg on my face. Turns out I was looking at a “comment” to my original post. That's where I saw the single up arrow & flag. It's the “answers” that have both up & down arrows & a check mark. Still learning how to use the forum after all these years.

Comment: @aksarben:  No worries at all. I'm glad we got there.