# What is the equivalent of the Bash ` (backquote/backtick) in Windows PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, syntax

I need the result of a command to be taken as a parameter in another command.

```
command /opt <another command output>
```

On Bash Linux I would do

```
command /opt `another command`
```

What is the equivalent of the ` symbol that works in Windows Terminal?

In particular, I am using the command

```
'C:\Program Files\Display\display64.exe' /listdevices | findstr 22MP55 | %{$_ -replace "- .*",""}
```

where `findstr` is the windows equivalent to `grep` and the final command in the pipe is the equivalent to `sed`. The output of this command will be 1, 2 or 3, and I need this to be passed to the `%HERE` in the following line

```
'C:\Program Files\Display\display64.exe' /device %HERE /rotate 90
```

The following minimal example, does not work:

```
FOR /F %a in ('"C:\Program Files\Display\display64.exe"  /listdevices | findstr 22MP55 | %{$_ -replace "- .*",""}') do echo "%a"
```

What I am doing wrong? (I am new in Windows).

Comment: Why use a .bat file at all?

Comment: I was trying to define a shortcut to rotate my monitor (which I did), not to write a .bat file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `(...)`, the [grouping operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#grouping-operator--) to pass output from a command as an argument to another command:

```
'C:\Program Files\Display\display64.exe' /device (
  'C:\Program Files\Display\display64.exe' /listdevices | findstr 22MP55 | %{$_ -replace "- .*",""}
) /rotate 90
```

Note: `$(...)`, the [subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#subexpression-operator--), works too, but `(...)` is usually sufficient and has no side effects; you only need `$(...)` for *multiple* (`;`-separated) statements - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67695014/45375) for details.

---

As for **what you tried**:

- In POSIX-compatible shells such as Bash, `` `...` `` is the legacy form of a *command substitution* whose modern syntax is `$(...)` - while PowerShell supports `$(...)` too, `(...)` is usually preferable, as noted.
- In PowerShell, `` ` `` serves as the *escape character* (only), analogous to `\` in POSIX-compatible shells - see the conceptual [about_Special_Characters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Special_Characters) help topic.
- Your attempts to use `FOR /F %a in ...` and `%HERE` (which should be `%HERE%`) relate to the *legacy `cmd.exe` shell* on Windows, not to its successor, PowerShell, whose syntax differs fundamentally.

Comment: Thank you. It works in PowerShell. For some reason it does not work in a shortcut icon I created in the desktop. I tried with `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -command "'C:\Program Files\Display\display64.exe' /device $('C:\Program Files\Display\display64.exe' /listdevices | findstr 22MP55 | %{$_ -replace '- .*',''}) /rotate 0"` but does not work.

Comment: `$( )` is good for inserting multiple statements seperated by a semicolon, like `$(echo hi; echo there)`

Comment: I made it: `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -command "& 'C:\Program Files\Display\display64.exe' /device (& 'C:\Program Files\Display\display64.exe' /listdevices | findstr 22MP55 | %{$_ -replace \"- .*\",\"\"}) /rotate 0"`. I had to scape the double quote.

Comment: Indeed, @AlejandroDC: When calling via PowerShell's _CLI_ (`powershell.exe` for _Windows PowerShell_, `pwsh` for _PowerShell (Core) 7+_) from the outside using `-Command` / `c`, you need to _escape_ `"` chars. to be passed through as part of the command: `\"` works in principle, but can break on the `cmd.exe` side when calling from there. In that case, use `"^""` (sic) with `powershell.exe`, and `""` with `pwsh.exe`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49060341/45375) for details.