# Issue with using properties in an array and custom calculated property

Tags: powershell, active-directory

So I have the following code that ingests AD users on a domain controller. The following throws an error:

```
# User Props to select
$user_props = @(
        'Name',
        'DistinguishedName',
        'SamAccountName',
        'Enabled',
        'SID'
        )

# Get AD groups an AD user is a member of
$user_groups = @{ label = 'GroupMemberships'; expression = { (Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $_.DistinguishedName).Name } }

# Get AD Users
$users = Get-ADUser -Filter * -Property $user_props | Select-Object $user_props, $user_groups -ErrorAction Stop -ErrorVariable _error
```

However, if I were to change `$users` to the following:

```
$users = Get-ADUser -Filter * -Property $user_props | Select-Object Name, DistinguishedName, SamAccountName, Enabled, SID, $user_groups -ErrorAction Stop -ErrorVariable _error
```

I no longer get this error. Is there a way I can define `$user_props` such that I don't need to type out each property and still use my custom calculated property `$user_groups`?

I believe the issue has to do with mixing an array (`$user_props`) with a hashtable (`$user_groups`) but I'm unsure how to best write this. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to "concatenate" two variables into one flat array is to use the `@(...)` array subexpression operator:

```
... |Select-Object @($user_props;$user_groups) ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Since this issue keeps coming up, let me complement [Mathias R. Jessen's effective solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73390047/45375) with some **background** information:

- [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object)'s (potentially positionally implied) **`-Property` parameter requires a *flat* array of property names and/or [calculated properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Calculated_Properties)** (for brevity, both referred to as just *property names* below).
- Therefore, **if you need to *combine* two variables containing *arrays* of property names, or combine *literally* enumerated property name(s) with such variables**, you must ***explicitly construct a flat array***.

Therefore, simply placing `,` between your array variables does *not* work, because it creates a *jagged* (nested) array:

```bash
  # Two arrays with property names.
  $user_props = @('propA', 'propB')
  $user_groups = @('grpA', 'grpB')

  # !! WRONG: This passes a *jagged* array, not a flat one.
  # -> ERROR: "Cannot convert System.Object[] to one of the following types 
  #           {System.String, System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock}."
  'foo' | Select-Object $user_props, $user_groups

  # !! WRONG:
  # The same applies if you tried to combine one or more *literal* property names 
  # with an array variable.
  'foo' | Select-Object 'propA', $user_groups
  'foo' | Select-Object $user_groups, 'propA', 'propB'
```

That is, `$user_props, $user_groups` effectively passes 
`@( @('propA', 'propB'), @('grpA', 'grpB') )`, i.e. a *jagged* (nested) array,

whereas what you need to pass is 
`@('propA', 'propB', 'grpA', 'grpB')`, i.e. a *flat* array.

Mathias' solution is convenient in that you needn't know or care whether `$user_props` and `$user_groups` contain *arrays* or just a single property name, due to how **`@(...)`, the [array-subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#array-subexpression-operator--)** works - the result will be a flat array:

```bash
# Note how the variable references are *separate statements*, whose
# output @(...) collects in an array:
'foo' | Select-Object @($user_props; $user_groups)

# Ditto, with a literal property name.
# Note the need to *quote* the literal name in this case.
'foo' | Select-Object @('propA'; $user_groups)
```

In practice it won't make a difference for this use case, so this is a **convenient and pragmatic solution**, but generally it's worth noting that `@(...)` *enumerates* array variables used as statements inside it, and then collects the results in a *new* array. That is, both `$user_props` and `$user_groups` are sent to the pipeline *element by element*, and the resulting, combined elements are collected in a new array.

**A direct way to flatly concatenate arrays** (or append a single element to an array) is to use the **`+` operator with (at least) an array-valued *LHS***. This, of necessity, returns a *new* array that is copy of the LHS array with the element(s) of the RHS directly appended:

```bash
# Because $user_props is an *array*, "+" returns an array with the RHS
# element(s) appended to the LHS element.
'foo' | Select-Object ($user_props + $user_groups)
```

If you're not sure if `$user_props` is an *array*, you can simply cast to `[array]`, which also works with a single, literal property name:

```bash
# The [array] cast ensures that $user_props is treated as an array, even if it isn't one.
# Note:
#   'foo' | Select-Object (@($user_props) + $user_groups) 
#    would work too, but would again needlessly enumerate the array first.
'foo' | Select-Object ([array] $user_props + $user_groups)

# Ditto, with a single, literal property name
'foo' | Select-Object ([array] 'propA' + $user_groups)

# With *multiple* literal property names (assuming they come first), the
# cast is optional:
'foo' | Select-Object ('propA', 'propB'  +  $user_groups)
```

Note:

- The above uses `(...)`, the [grouping operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#grouping-operator--), in order to pass *expressions* as arguments to a command - while you frequently see `$(...)`, the [subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#subexpression-operator--) used instead, this is *not* necessary and can have unwanted side effects - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67695014/45375).
- `@(...)` isn't strictly needed to declare array *literals*, such as `@('foo', 'bar')` - `'foo', 'bar'` is sufficient, though you may prefers enclosing in `@(...)` for visual clarity. In *argument* [parsing mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Parsing), quoting is *optional* for simple strings, so that `Write-Output foo, name` is the simpler alternative to `Write-Output @('foo', 'name')`
- `,`, the [array constructor operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#comma-operator-), has perhaps surprisingly high [precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operator_Precedence), so that `1, 2 + 3` is parsed as `(1, 2) + 3`, resulting in `1, 2, 3`